# AspNetUsers Table recovery

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a Web Api which is hosted on Azure. This project has Individual User Account authentication in it.

I have accidentally deleted the AspNetUsers table from my project and I do not know if it is possible to get it back. I have also deleted the _MigrationHistory table so I cannot get it back from there.

Is there any way to retrieve this table or even create a new one with identical columns. It does not matter about the missing User data I just need to be able to Register Users again.

I am using Entity Framework Code First. I tried adding a migration and updating the database but this does not work.

I think creating a new project is a last resort fix but I really don't want to have to do that!

Comment: you could just create a new project, and copy the files relating to your AspNetUsers table into your new project?

Comment: It's a very big project... As I said, that is my last resort but I am looking for something to save me all that time and work!

Comment: can you show the migration your tried? Are you getting any errors when updating the database?

Comment: The migration is blank in both the up and down methods.. It doesn't seem to realise that it is missing? There is no errors on any activity with the database until I try to register a user or get a token for an existing user.. But that is probably because there is no more existing users!

Comment: what version of mvc are you using? which version of EF?

Comment: Its an ASP .NET Web Api 2 application using Entity Framework 6 Code First

Comment: I have just created a new project and it seems to be working fine. Took a while though!